# Fancybox and Jquery Implementation

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

New to this but making progress. I am using Fancybox as a lightbox, but want to have one thumbnail open multiple images. I found [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uZCC6/):

**HTML:**

```
<a class="fancybox" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg"><img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_s.jpg" alt=""/></a>

<div class="hidden">
<a class="fancybox" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_b.jpg"><img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_s.jpg" alt=""/></a>

<a class="fancybox" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/3_b.jpg"><img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/3_s.jpg" alt=""/></a>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(".fancybox")
    .attr('rel', 'gallery')
    .fancybox({
        padding : 0
    });
```

I copied the HTML and pasted it into my document. Images show, but all thumbnails. Took the CSS in the upper right, pasted to the fancybox.css file. Great, now 3 images to one thumbnail, but it also includes any other images on page. I must need to add the .js, below the HTML box in the above jsfiddle document but I am stumped as to what file I need to add this code to.

Comment: "Please make your question complete by including relevant, formatted code inline (don't just link to jsfiddle.net)." - this is what happens when you make that link into a link. Please take the advice, and don't try to work around it (if that was what the `>>` and `<<` were about)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear really, as Jeff suggested try to examplain with examples. 
if you mean this part of the code

```
$(".fancybox")
    .attr('rel', 'gallery')
    .fancybox({
        padding : 0
    });
```

This needs to be added to the your html page where you placing this Fancy Box, and you will place it inside a `<script></script>` and put it in on `page load` event.

Comment: Sorry...as mentioned, truly a newbie. I have tried a few examples and can get multiple imagers per thumbnail, but it shows all images on the page. I just want it to show each gallery and not have it "jump" to the next set of images. I,m sorry, but what isvanpage load event? My demo page with some examples is here: http://www.hirezgraphics.com/portfolio/demo/. Thanks!